# Can't return recordcount with the stored procedure with the declaration in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2000

I wrote a stored procedure to return the record but as soon as I declare a variable my asp classic can't do count the total recordset, it always returns -1

If anyone has the solution to this problem it would make my job a lot easier and your input would be greatly appreciated.

Stored proceedure code for SQL Server 2000

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SalesTaxV3(
    @ship_zip varchar(20)
)
AS
   --problem  if in enable the next 2 lines
   DECLARE @tax_rate INT
   set @tax_rate =0
   --disable the above 2 line the asp will able to count.   
   --end problem
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tax_rate where  zip =''+@ship_zip+''  
END
```

ASP Classic code:

```
<%
set strGetTaxZips = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
strSQLGetTaxZips = "EXECUTE sp_SalesTaxV3 '"&user_zip &"'"
Response.Write(strSQLGetTaxZips)
strGetTaxZips.Open strSQLGetTaxZips,tax_db,3
Response.Write("<BR>recordcount" &strGetTaxZips.recordcount)
%>
```

Comment: what's happening to the HTML editor, it doesn't show up on this website.

Comment: Why are you concatenating an empty string to @ship_zip? Since it is already a string, why not simply use `zip = @ship_zip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to put the `DECLARE` **after** the `BEGIN`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SalesTaxV3(@ship_zip varchar(20))
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @tax_rate INT
   SET @tax_rate = 0

   SELECT * FROM tax_rate WHERE zip = ''+@ship_zip+''  
END
```

Comment: found some tips http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-does-recordcount-return-as-1.html

Comment: @Darwin: silly question: if you only set the variable, but never use it anywhere, in any way, shape or form - why even bother with it??

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `Set NoCount On;` at the top of your stored procedure. The problem is likely that something is causing a list of rows affected to be returned and that is throwing off classic ADO and it thinks that rows affected is the first recordset.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SalesTaxV3 ( @ship_zip varchar(20) )
AS 
Begin
    Declare @tax_rate int

    Set NoCount On

    Set @tax_rate = 0

    Select * 
    From tax_rate 
    Where zip = @ship_zip
End
```

**Addition**

If the problem is getting an accurate value for the RecordCount property on the RecordSet, then the type of Cursor you use makes a difference. In your example, you are using a Static cursor by passing "3" to the Open method. Using a Static cursor, you need to call MoveLast before RecordCount will be accurate.

```
Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Dim sql
Dim rs

' btw, you should validate your inputs here
sql = "Exec sp_SalesTaxV3 '" & user_zip & "'"

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open sql, tax_db, adOpenStatic
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst  'not needed if you are not going to cycle through the rows

'Now RecordSet will be accurate
Response.Write( "<br />RecordCount: " & rs.RecordCount )

Set rs = Nothing
```

Btw, another solution is to simply return the row count as a column in the output (or just the count if you are not going to use any of the rows returned ).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SalesTaxV3 ( @ship_zip varchar(20) )
AS 
Begin
    Declare @tax_rate int

    Set NoCount On

    Set @tax_rate = 0

    Select * 
        , (Select Count(*)
            From tax_rate As T1
            Where zip = @ship_zip ) as RowCount
    From tax_rate 
    Where zip = @ship_zip
End
```

Comment: i already to that too. I've tried Set NoCount On; and also the Set NoCount Off; I have to use this code to work around with this problem. if not strGetTaxZips.eof then ...end if

Comment: @Darwin - Is it that the recordset's BOF and EOF are both True (i.e. -1)?

Comment: lol, that was the shorthand code. 
According to w3schools.com
The  EOF property returns True (-1) if the current record position is after the last record in the Recordset, otherwise it returns False (0). 
The The  BOF property returns True (-1) if the current record position is before the first record in the Recordset, otherwise it returns False (0).

Comment: @Darwin - IIRC, if you do not set the cursor to be Forward Only, then you need to use MoveFirst to get the to first row.

Comment: @Darwin - Looking closer at your code, you are using a Static cursor (the "3" in your recordset Open method call). That means you need to call MoveFirst to get to the first row. If you want a recordcount, you need to MoveLast before the RecordCount will be accurate.

Comment: @Darwin - I've updated my answer. I think the issue is that you need to MoveLast. Btw, if all you want is the count, you could obviously alter the stored proc to simply return the count to you rather than getting all the rows and counting how many you got.

Comment: thanks for the help guys. i was not worry about but many records can it return. I went a head and wrote a different asp code to check the state.

set strGetTaxZips = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    strSQLGetTaxZips = "EXECUTE sp_SalesTaxV3'"&user_zip &"'"
    strGetTaxZips.Open strSQLGetTaxZips,tax_db,3
 if strGetTaxZips.state=1 then
  if not strGetTaxZips.eof then 
  SaleTaxPercent=strGetTaxZips("tax_rate")
  SalesTax=SaleTaxPercent*dblTotalPrice
  GrandTotal=GrandTotal+SalesTax
  end if
 end if

Thanks so much for all of your inputs